# Eigenvalues from LDLT with all L=1

Tags: svd

I have a matrix in LDLT $X=LDL^T$ form, where all nonzero elements in L (i.e. diagonal and below), are $1$. So only D matters (which is diagonal).
What can we tell about the eigenvalues/vectors of this matrix?

It is possible to assume for simplicity that $X$ is positive definite, i.e. D's diagonal is all positive.

Comment: Did this question just change completely?

Comment: yes, but it's completely equivalent to the previous one!

Comment: I may be missing something, but in the previous question, $U$ had ones above and on the diagonal from bottom left to upper right instead of the usual triangular?

Comment: this is the conjugate case, of the inverse $X^-1$. invert a matrix with L having all 1 as described here, and you'll get 1 in the diagonal and -1 in the subdiagonal, and zero elsewhere.

Comment: i.e., the inverse of the X here is tridiagonal

Comment: Not sure if this is the sort of thing you are looking for, but Sylvester's law of inertia shows that the number of negative (zero, positive, resp.) eigenvalues of $X$ is the same as the number of negative (zero, positive, resp.) diagonal values of $D$. (Of course, this only requires $L$ to be invertible, so presumably one can say more here.)

Comment: We can assume full rank and all positive eigenvalues, i.e. we can assume $X$ is symmetric and positive definite. 
Also, L is invertible in our case. The problem is that its vectors are only independent, not orthogonal.
But as expected I need the eigenvalues themselves, not their count. Thanks!!!